# W3 Schools slideshow doesn't automatically load page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used the W3Schools example on how to load a slideshow, and the animations work perfectly, but it only comes up with three dots. I have to click on one of them for the picture to show up.

```js
    var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
 * {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
    <div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="images/slideshow/canarywharf.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Our headquarters in London, England.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="images/slideshow/new_york.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">The view from our offices in New York, USA.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="images/slideshow/frankfurt.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Our offices in Frankfurt, Germany.</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: do you mean the next & previous buttons arent loaded?

Comment: no, the actual pictures aren't loading until i click the dots.

Comment: I cant reproduce the problem. Made a fiddle, check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/53dd84yu/

Comment: Oh. It does work on the fiddle, but not on the browser, curiously enough. Maybe I'll upload it to github and post the link here.

Comment: Do you have your javascript code in a separate file or inside the html (using <script></script>? If you are using a separate file, could you show where it is being imported?

Comment: I'm using the JavaScript in the html using <script>

Comment: and where are you including the `<script>`? Within the head or before the `</body>`?

Comment: I'm putting it in the head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is related with the loading of the javascript code because you are loading it within the head element and in this case you have to ensure that the javascript code is executed when the DOM is loaded.

To solve it you can load the javascript code before the `</body>` tag to ensure that the DOM is loaded before the javascript is executed

Another approach could be to use jQuery to see when the document is ready, you could do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   showSlides(slideIndex);
});
```

But I prefer to load the javascript code at the bottom instead of using jQuery to avoid using another library. Besides, in my opinion it has a better performance because, if the javascript code is executed at the top of the document, it will be a visual delay before the end user sees the actual page.